# How to run and debug a C++ Android program in Eclipse

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, cmake

Thanks to [cmake-android-chain](https://code.google.com/p/android-cmake/source/browse/toolchain/android.toolchain.cmake), I can build a C++ program successfully. By using adb commands, I can also make the program run in Android devices:

```
adb push c_plus_plus_program /data/local/tmp/c_plus_plus_program
adb shell chmod -777 /data/local/tmp/c_plus_plus_program
adb shell ./data/local/tmp/c_plus_plus_program
```

Now I want to debug this program in Eclipse. With cmake, I can create a project for Eclipse, and I have also succeeded in building the project. However, the problem is I do not know how to run the program insider Eclipse, hence debugging the program. Any ideas? Thanks.